# Is php's 'include' a function or a statement?

Tags: php, include

There are plenty of examples of both on the web. The php manual says "The include() statement [...]", which seems contradictory - if it's a statement shouldn't it not have parenthesis?

Both of these work:

```
include('somefile.php');
include 'somefile.php;
```

So should I or anyone else care?

Comment: Nope, one should never care without certain reason.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Quoting from the manual (my emphasis)

> Because include() is a **special language construct**, parentheses are **not** needed around its argument.

These are also called "special forms", and include such things as `echo` and `return` statements. Note that while none of these are functions, you can still speak of expressions and statements, the difference being the former have a value while the latter don't. Since `include`, `include_once`, `require` and `require_once` all return a value (`TRUE` if the include was successful), they can be used in expressions. By this reasoning, "include statement" would be incorrect, though `include`s are almost always used as statements.

Comment: If they are not functions, how can they "return" something?

Comment: @Marc.2377 In the same way that most expressions in PHP can return something (e.g. the expression `1+2` will return a value `3`, and that can be assigned to a variable `$x = 1+2`); return values aren't limited to functions

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wish the manual was as technical and complete as this answer is.

Answer (score 9):

include is a statement :
Explain by following eg

```
// won't work, evaluated as include(('vars.php') == 'OK'), i.e. include('')
if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}

// works
if ((include 'vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Comment: This really isn't a negative example, as putting parenthesis around the `include` does not preclude putting parenthesis around the argument. `if ( (include('vars.php')) == 'OK' ) { echo 'OK'; }`.

Answer (score 6):

The parentheses are parameters for a function. 
With `include` you can use it either as a function or a statement in php.

> Because include() is a special language construct, parentheses are not
>   needed around its argument.

Documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

With `echo` same concept, quoting from the PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
>   are not **required** to use parentheses with it. echo (unlike some other
>   language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot
>   always be used in the context of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Single values within parens evaluate to the value itself, so the parens themselves are of no consequence.

Answer (score 1):

Both. In many areas of the PHP documentation, everything is referred to as a statement. Example (from control structures) - "A statement can be an assignment, a function call, a loop, a conditional statement or even a statement that does nothing (an empty statement)."

The difference between a statement and a functions is a matter of the semantics of the individual language. Thus, it's up the PHP maintainers to either explicitly define this, or let it remain ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

`include`, `require`, `echo`, `print`, and a handful of other keywords are language constructs on their own, rather than function calls, and do not need parentheses. However, some people like to pretend they're function calls and use parentheses anyway. They are identical.

Answer (score 0):

for echo always use **echo "test"**

```
<?php 
// this will give you error
echo ("test","test");

//that will work fine
echo "test","test";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Statements having only one parameter, can have also parenthesis, e.g:

```
echo ('hello world');
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the only difference is what you want to do.

For example, these two

```
echo 'Hello World';
echo ('Hello World');
```

...both print *Hello World*.

It is just what you want to do, what you feel most comfortable with, and if you're like me, you want to make your script look pretty :D