# When should I use parenthesis in require/include statements?

Tags: php, joomla

I've been handed a pile of code that includes a lot of `require`/`include` statments (mixed between `require` and `require_once`).  Sometimes, the path has parenthesis around it, i.e. `require_once (JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controller.php');`, and other times there isn't: `require_once $path;`.

The php docs for include [mention this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), but aren't specific.  Should I remove the parenthesis when I find them, or is it ok to leave them alone?  When writing further require/include statements, are there specific cases where I should use them?

Comment: Related question: [Is php's 'include' a function or a statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955732/is-phps-include-a-function-or-a-statement)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are allowed to use parentheses in 'include/require' not because include allows it itself but because you can use parentheses around any string or number in PHP for grouping.

So for example, `"dog"` is equivalent to `("dog")`, `("dog")."dog"` is equivalent to `"dog"."dog"`, etc.

Parentheses become useful when you use complex expressions involving calculations and string concatenations but in such a simple case, they are simply allowed and perform an unnecessary and harmless "grouping" of a single string value.

Comment: @FellipeSanches you are reproducing incomplete/wrong information. `if`, `while`, `switch`, `for` and many other statements require parentheses, yet they are clearly not functions.

Answer (score 2):

Both syntaxes are valid. So, it's up to you. :)
The documentation explains:

> Because include is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument.

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue with leaving them or taking them out, at the end of the day it is up to the comfort of the developer.

Personally, I leave them off. I think it looks a little cleaner, and the IDE syntax coloring works a bit better.