# can not compile a virtual file in PHP extension

Tags: php, c++, c, php-extension

i am coding a PHP extension , i modify the  `zend_compile_file` to my own function here is the source code :

```
FILE *bravery_ext_fopen(FILE *fp)
{
struct  stat    stat_buf;
char    *datap, *newdatap;
int datalen, newdatalen;
char sign[] = "BRAVERY";
int cryptkey_len = sizeof(sign);

fstat(_fileno(fp), &stat_buf);
datalen = stat_buf.st_size -  sizeof(sign);
datap = (char*)malloc(datalen);
fread(datap, datalen, 1, fp);
fclose(fp);

fp = tmpfile();

fwrite(datap, datalen-1, 1, fp);

free(datap);


rewind(fp);
return fp;
}
zend_op_array *bravery_compile_file(zend_file_handle *file_handle, int type TSRMLS_DC)
{
FILE    *fp;
char sign[] = "BRAVERY";
char    buf[8];
char    fname[128];

memset(fname, 0, sizeof fname);
if (zend_is_executing(TSRMLS_C)) {
    if (get_active_function_name(TSRMLS_C)) {
        strncpy(fname, get_active_function_name(TSRMLS_C), sizeof fname - 2);
    }
}
if (fname[0]) {
    if ( strcasecmp(fname, "show_source") == 0
      || strcasecmp(fname, "highlight_file") == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
}

fp = fopen(file_handle->filename, "r");
if (!fp) {
    return org_compile_file(file_handle, type TSRMLS_CC);
}

fread(buf, 7, 1, fp);
if (memcmp(buf, sign, 7) != 0) {
    fclose(fp);
    return org_compile_file(file_handle, type TSRMLS_CC);
}

if (file_handle->type == ZEND_HANDLE_FP) fclose(file_handle->handle.fp);
if (file_handle->type == ZEND_HANDLE_FD) close(file_handle->handle.fd);
file_handle->handle.fp = bravery_ext_fopen(fp);
file_handle->type = ZEND_HANDLE_FP;
//file_handle->opened_path = expand_filepath(file_handle->filename, NULL TSRMLS_CC);
file_handle->opened_path = NULL;
return org_compile_file(file_handle, type TSRMLS_CC);
}
```

its works good on normal PHP files,
BUT it gives me a `Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\php5411\1.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0` error to me when the phpfile start with "BRAVERY"(this is what i am using to sign my php file).

here is the debug info of file_handle.Could any one help me? sorry for the google docs link cause i cannot post image here

[img link](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1oedSkx_MQce88rYdkYdSrvQajswbpUGLcC-b-RpHzkk/pub?w=960&h=720)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem that people new to PHP have. I understand the frustration as this happened to me when I was new and couldn't find the answer. The "require" statement requires that you do not use parentheses. If you use parenthesis it will treat it like a logic statement. Since the statement is ("ThisIsAstring") it's interpreted as true or 1 (it's not an empty string). Remove the parentheses. :D

EDIT: As a note, when you have a semi-ambiguous error like that, you should really include **all** of the source code.

Here's a good answer found on stackoverflow: [When should I use parenthesis in require/include statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918598/when-should-i-use-parenthesis-in-require-include-statements)

Comment: sorry , i am writing a PHP Extension with C++ , not writing PHP code.

Comment: In that case, it's extremely odd that you're getting "Failed opening required 'C:\php5411\1.php'" unless you **are** explicitly including or requiring it. I apologize for the misunderstanding.

Comment: If i remove my extension it works fine. Thank you for your help.