# require_once format produces different behaviours

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt, require-once

I'm trying to find the ideal way to integrate files into others throughout a directory hierarchy in my project.

I've noticed that the following works in Eclipse PDT:

1. `require_once '/../../services/impl/UserService.php';`
2. `require_once ('ui/controller/AbstractController.php');`
3. `require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myproject/daos/impl/UserDAO.php';`
4. `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../AsbtractDAO.php';`

All of these resolve yet the way they're formulated is completely different. Any ideas why ?

In particular the path in brackets (2) resolves but doesn't when the same path is between single quotes.

Also, what are the pros/cons of each ? What standard could I adopt that's the most robust ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first two, I'm guessing you're asking about whether or not to use parenthesis.
For that, take a look at this answer:
[When should I use parenthesis in require/include statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918598/when-should-i-use-parenthesis-in-require-include-statements)
Essentially you can use either, but for readability it's best to be consistent, whichever you choose. The first style seems to be more common.

Using absolute paths *can* speed up performance, since using a relative path will instruct PHP to look through everything in the include_path. Require can accept either a relative or absolute, much like any other language's include calls.

The third will pass an absolute path to the require. However, there are potential issues with `$SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` (e.g. it doesn't work on some IIS servers).

In the fourth you're using the file's absolute path from `dirname(__FILE__)` -- also `__DIR__` in PHP >= 5.3. You can also do this by defining a constant with the path. If you're going for code golf, this would be the most keystrokes, but it *may* improve performance, depending on how many files would need to be scanned in your include_path when importing a relative location.

Summary:

1. Pros: easiest to read. Cons: may be slower due to use of relative paths
2. Same as 1 - stylistic difference only.
3. Pros: may be faster due to use of absolute paths. Cons - won't work on some web servers
4. Pros: may be faster due to use of absolute paths. Cons - more long-winded

Comment: Note that 1 & 2 seem to behave differently. `ui/controller/...` (ui is a directory just inside the one used by my project) will not work in the same way between simple quotes and I have to resort to relative paths. Unsure as to the why. This may just be a quirk with Eclipse PDT.

Comment: Also, if you have any recommendations on the best way to manage inclusions, I'm all ears. Perhaps set a variable somewhere to application directory and derive absolute paths from it ? Not comfortable enough with autoload to use it right now.

Comment: For #2 - is the ui folder in the same directory as the file that's trying to include it? That looks like a relative path if it's not the top directory.

Comment: The file that has `require_once ('ui/controller/AbstractController.php')` is actually inside the controller directory, the full path being '/myproject/ui/controller/'. It does seem to be a quirk with Eclipse. Launching the file on localhost does produce a failed to open stream error.

Comment: Also, the reason it does not appear to produce an error when the actual web app is running is probably because url rewriting is channeling all requests through index.php in `/myproject/`. I really need to sort out these inclusions. Looks like absolute paths are my best bet.

Comment: Yeah that's strange then. Absolute paths are probably the best bet in general.