# Include in PHP is ineffective

Tags: php, html, include

I have created a file called *index.php*, and inside the same folder as *index.php* there is a folder called *"includes"*.

Inside it are two PHP files, *head.php* and *header.php*. The problem is that those two files are not being included into index.php. Now, I have searched all over Stack Overflow, and I can't seem to find the answer.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <?php include 'includes/head.php'; ?>

    <body>
        <?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
        <div id="container">
            <aside>
                <div class="widget">
                    <h2>Widget Header</h2>
                    <div class="inner">
                        Widget contents
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Try with `<?php echo include ('includes/head.php'); ?>`

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I had problems with a CMS called phpVMS for using `php include` instead of `php echo include`

Comment: @ctabuyo well, we'll see what the OP has to say (that's if they're reading comments here); but I doubt it. However, crazier things have happened ;-)

Comment: I am not exactly sure whether or not I use error reporting functions properly, but at this point none errors are being reported.

Comment: @canthandlehtml question is now, if you have a webserver/PHP installed, if it's properly configured, and how you're accessing this. As `http://localhost/file.php` or as `c://file.php` in your web browser? Those are 2 different animals altogether.

Comment: Use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to "display" if any. and my comment just above this one.

Comment: @ctabuyo It does solve it :/

Comment: @canthandlehtml if you had any echos in that other file, then you wouldn't need to echo the include also. had you shown us what you had in those files to start with.

Comment: I am indeed accessing it as c://file.php, I was not aware this might be a problem, forgive for the inadequacy, php is something completely new for me

Comment: It would have been useful to have seen the contents of `head.php` !

Comment: well there you go, there's the problem ^^^^^ @RamRaider edit: you broke my reply arrows hahahaha

Comment: @canthandlehtml ok "what" exactly solves "what" here??

Comment: what do you mean? haha :D

Comment: @canthandlehtml I believe I "answered" that and have posted it below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per my comment to the OP:

> *@canthandlehtml question is now, if you have a webserver/PHP installed, if it's properly configured, and how you're accessing this. As `http://localhost/file.php` or as `c://file.php in` your web browser? Those are 2 different animals altogether. – Fred -ii-*

As per your comment:

> *I am indeed accessing it as c://file.php, I was not aware this might be a problem, forgive for the inadequacy, php is something completely new for me*

You're accessing it as `c://file.php` instead of `http://localhost/file.php` which is the reason why your includes don't work.

A web browser will not parse/execute PHP directives in that manner. It requires it to be running through a host with a web server/PHP installed, running and properly configured.

Sidenote:

The code that are to be included should "echo" something in order to "show" something, if that is the intention; to echo HTML etc.

Seeing `<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>` then I take it you have a form of navigation menu.

If it contains something like:

```
<?php
    $var = "Hello world";
```

and it is not "echo'd", then it won't show up in your rendered HTML, it needs to be echo'd.

```
<?php
    echo $var = "Hello world"; // this is a valid directive
                               // it both echo's and assigns
```

It's unsure if `<?php include 'includes/head.php'; ?>` contains meta's, or CSS to be included etc. and if it does contain `<head></head>` tags. If not, then you will need to add those if you are including that, or JS that is required to be in head tags, etc.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to fix it and respond shortly.

Comment: I mean thanks a LOT :D I was trying to wrap my head around the concepts of php for quite some time, it's clearer now ;)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the webpages are being accessed via a webserver rather than directly from the filesystem then using / setting the `include_path` should help alleviate the issue ( that said, use `echo` within the included files is the more usual approach! )

You can include a file using the filesystem path but you cannot run / execute php in a browser without the webserver.

```
<?php
    /* Once the include path is set it is easy to include the file by name alone */
    set_include_path( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'includes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php 
            include('head.php');
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
            include('header.php');
        ?>
        <div id='container'>
            <aside>
                <div class='widget'>
                    <h2>Widget Header</h2>
                    <div class='inner'>
                        Widget contents
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's another way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
include("includes/head.php");
```

Comment: @ArjanShrestha `include` is not a function, and thus does not require parenthesis around it. (See [include docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)). It's most likely a path-issue.

Comment: @Qirel Ok got it thanks, but it works fine with parenthesis also, does it make any difference??

Comment: It works, yes, but it's not a function - so you don't need it. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10918598/4535200