# USE require 'abc.php' or require('abc.php')

Tags: php, include, require

Does it make a difference whether I use `require 'abc.php'` or `require('abc.php')`? Does one of them have an advantage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use parenthesis in require/include statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918598/when-should-i-use-parenthesis-in-require-include-statements)

Comment: @Ivar exactly :)