# Page not loading after php include

Tags: php, html

I have a page which includes the menu bar (a php page). This works, but strangely the page doesn't load after the include.

Some code:

```
<div class="center">
<?php
include ('../menu.php')
?>
<div class="text" id="media">
Some text
</div>
```

When I add the

```
<div class="text" id="media">
Some text
</div>
```

to the menu.php it is showed, but not when it is on the parent page. Anybody has an idea? There isn't any warning or error showing.

```
<!-- begin menu -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../style/menu.css">
<div class="menu_b">
<div class="logo">
<a href="../../../../index.php"><img src="../../../../afbeeldingen/menu/logo.gif" width="375" title="Home" /></a>
</div>
<div class="aangemeld">
</div>
<ul class="menu_tekst">
    <li class="<?php echo $account_li;?>"><a class="nt" href="../../../../account.php">Account</a></li>
    <li class="tussenstuk"></li>
    <li class="<?php echo $contact_li;?>"><a class="nt href="../../../../contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="tussenstuk"></li>
    <li class="<?php echo $fotos_li;?>"><a class="nt" href="../../../../fotos.php">Foto's</a>
    <ul class="sub_fotos sub">
        <li class="space_left">&nbsp;</li>
        <li class="titel_blok_sub"><a class="nt" href="../../../../fotos/2013_2014.php">2013-2014</a></li>
        <li class="titel_blok_sub"><a class="nt" href="../../../../fotos/kamp.php">Kampfoto's 2014</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tussenstuk"></li>
    <li class="nt"><a class="nt" href="../../../../winkelwagen.php">winkelwagen + besteld</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="onder_menu">
</div>
<div class="sub_menu">
</div>
<!-- einde menu -->
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'parent page'?

Comment: What is in the `menu.php` ?

Comment: Turn on the error reporting and says us what error you getting, Or Do you have anything in the `menu.php` file ??

Comment: Add a semi-colon `include ('../menu.php');` see if that makes it kick in.

Comment: @Fred-ii- PHP allows you to leave out the `;` before `?>`.

Comment: The parent page is the page wich include the menu.php page. I will add the menu.php content in just a bit!

Comment: Well then, it's a path issue.

Comment: I don't think it's the cause of the problem, but you're missing a `</div>` to match the first `<div>`.

Comment: Take the parenthesis off the include statement. It should look like this:

include 'page.php';

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that I know. However, if OP has any other PHP below the include, then the semi-colon would need to be loaded. You know just as much as I that OP's often leave out details as such; having more PHP below, often never shown.

Comment: @Rings At this point then, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Also, include returns true if it was successful.  You could put the include in an if statement to check if its including the file.

Comment: @Rings Possible silly question, but I'll ask it anyway. Is the "parent page" `.php` or `.html`? And is there more PHP below `include ('../menu.php')`?

Comment: Added a ';' didn't make a difference, the menu.php is showing correctly and even if add error reporting, nothing is showing. All my pages are .php

Comment: Last ditch effort. As Barmar stated, you have a missing closing `</div>`. Plus, on LINUX `menu.php` is not the same as `Menu.php`, should your file be called that. Other than that, I have no more ideas except if you have something in `.htaccess` as a rewrite.

Comment: Solved it, above the div.center tag their was an include of a php page that didn't exist. Thanks everybody!

Comment: It pays to show *full code*. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above the div.center their was an other php include of a page that doesn't exist, after removing it, the page loaded. Didn't looked at it because it was above the menu.php which was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot semicolon ;

```
include ('../menu.php');
```

Comment: PHP automatically adds semicolon when you end the code block with `?>`.

Comment: The syntax should in fact be without parentheses at all (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955732/is-phps-include-a-function-or-a-statement)), but the semicolon doesn't actually matter at the end of a code block.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a quotation mark:

```
<li class="<?php echo $contact_li;?>">
    <a class="nt href="../../../../contact.php">Contact</a>
</li>
```

should be

```
<li class="<?php echo $contact_li;?>">
    <a class="nt" href="../../../../contact.php">Contact</a>
</li>
```

*Succes ermee*

Answer (score 0):

Try using `require`:

```
require('../menu.php');
```

Comment: This does not necessarily make a difference: the only difference between `include` and `require` is that `require` emits a fatal error on failure, whereas `include` only a warning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have turned off display errors in your php.ini and that menu.php doesn't exist.

If you are not sure how to turn on error reporting in your development machine, add the following lines to your parent page;

```
<div class="center">
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include ('../menu.php');
?>
<div class="text" id="media">
Some text
</div>
```

This should then reveal why the page is not being included.

Answer (score -1):

Take the parenthesis off the include statement. It should look like this:

`include 'page.php';`

Comment: That doesn't makes a difference! You can write: `echo "test";` and also `echo ("test");` this is the same with include!

Comment: @Rizier123 It doesn't make a difference, but it is correct syntax - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955732/is-phps-include-a-function-or-a-statement).

Comment: So? Answers are supposed to help solve the problem. Incidental suggestions should be posted as comments.